# TYT TH-350 unlocking to receive 160-161 MHz in the USA

Tags: vhf, tyt

Recently purchased the TYT TH-350 because it is triband. My version allows for TX/RX 144-148/222-225/420-450. Every other HT I own allows for extended
receive only. The TH-350 has a European version and a version that allows for 136-174/220-260/400-480. I like to listen for to the railroad frequencies. My TH-350 will not allow me to put in the 160-161 railroad frequencies. I have looked all over the place, but I can not figure out how to unlock it to receive 160-161. Does any one know how to unlock the radio to expand the receive capabilities?

Comment: what happens when you try to program one of those frequencies in memory using something like CHIRP?